# Docker and jre 11 in Debug mode

Tags: java, docker, debugging, remote-debugging, java-11

I was trying to get a remote debug session running on my docker container.

Actually the debug session always gets blocked by an IOException..

Dockerfile Entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-Xdebug", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=5005,suspend=n", "-jar","/backend.jar"]
```

Any ideas, whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

since java 9 you have to specify your adapter, or simply use an escaper for the debug host as such:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=*:5005,suspend=n
vs old (pre java 9)

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=5005,suspend=n
```

great documentation in openjdk btw..